# Exact string matches considering Case with COUNTIF

Tags: numbers

`=COUNTIF(B1:B7; "US")` counts *anything* with US us Us uS anywhere in the cell B1:B7
How to count ONLY *exact* matches to "US" accounting for case? (only that string, only capitalized)

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if this could be accomplished with a single formula, but as of this writing Numbers does not support Array formulas.

I was able to solve it by testing for "US" and returning "1" for true and "0" for false.

- Formula in adjacent or other column: `=IFERROR(FIND("US",A1),0)` and drag formula down. (The `FIND` function allows for Case testing.)
- Then using `=COUNTIF(range,1)` where `range` is the cells containing a "1" get the count.

Note: this can be made dynamic by changing the formula slightly.  If `Find()` is changed to look at a cell where the user can input the search criteria, then the result can be any of the variances.   `=IFERROR(FIND([absoluteCellReverenceWithCritera],A1),0)` - See last screenshots.

[image: Formula to test for US]

[image: Count true]

---

[image: Dynamic formula]

[image: Dynamic formula 2]